# PHP & Javascript: Dynamic search with 2 textbox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is there any way to have a dynamic search with 2 textbox to filter 2 different fields?

for example i have a table like:

[image]

and i have created somethin like this:
[image]

it already works in the LASTNAME textbox.

i want is that when i enter a lastname with same lastnames like this:
[image]

i want to add another filter by firstname, so that when i enter a firstname on the FIRSTNAME textbox example i enter PEDRO in the FIRSTNAME textbox only PEDRO A. Dela Cruz will show up.

This is my Codes

Index.php

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".lname").keyup(function() 
{ 
var value = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'lname='+ value;
if(searchlname!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchlname').val(decoded);
});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#searchlname').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
</script>

    <div class="content">
    Lastname:
    <input type="text" class="lname" id="searchlname" placeholder="Search for people" /><br />
    Firstname:
    <input type="text" class="search" id="" placeholder="Search for people" /><br /> 
<div id="result">
</div>
```

search.php

```
<table width="80%">
    <th width="5%">ID</th>
    <th width="40%">Name</th>
    <th width="10%">Action</th>
</table>

<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','admin') or die(mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db('dbvincent') or die(mysql_error());

if($_POST)
{
$search_name=$_POST['lname'];
$sql_res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tblpatients` WHERE `lname` LIKE '%$search_name%' order by `patient_id` LIMIT 15");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
$id = $row['patient_id'];   
$fname = $row['fname'];
$mname = $row['mname'];
$lname = $row['lname'];
?>
<table width="80%">
    <td width="5%"><?php echo $id ; ?></td>
    <td width="40%"><?php echo $fname.' '.$mname.' '.$lname; ?></td>
    <td width="10%"><button formaction="echoid.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>">Add</button></td>
</table>

<?php
```

thanks you.

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO. Specially since your not escaping the user input at all.

Comment: thanks for the concern. but im not concern of the security yet and the system ill be using will only be used in a small office..but i will try to convert it to mysqli. and thanks for the advise.

Comment: _Suggestion,_ at least escape the user input. If not, and someone searches for example `O'connor`, it will break your query (the `'` will end the value statement and `connor` will be considered an invalid SQL keyword).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson actually thats 1 of my problems. when im inserting data in my other page like PEOPLE's PARK, it won't save and i know the problems in on the `'`. but i don't really know how to fix it.

Comment: Just escape your user input. Since you want to stick with those deprecated `mysql_*`-functions, you can use: `$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);`. Just remember, if your site is out in the wild (a.k.a the internet), then you _really_ should use MySQLi or PDO with Prepeared Statements (just can't stress this enough). Escaping works to some extent, but aren't as safe as you might think.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oh. i have used this `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);` in my other page. and this will not be publish in the internet.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson but btw. do you have an idea on how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *There are cleaner ways of doing this, but instead if changing all your code, I've updated it to fit your needs. I've already nagged about the security aspect and about not using those old, deprecated `mysql_*`-functions, but rather Prepared Statements with MySQLi or PDO.*
>
> *It just needs to be pointed out in case someone else comes here later.*

First, I would give both input fields a new extra css class, example: `people-search-filter`,
I'm also giving the field for last name an ID :

```
<input type="text" class="lname people-search-filter" id="searchlname" ...

<input type="text" class="search people-search-filter" id="searchfname" ...
```

This allowes us the create the same event on both input fields:

```
$(function(){
    // We add the event on the class, which both inputs have
    $(".people-search-filter").keyup(function() { 
        // Now we get the values from both inputs, using their ID's
        var lname = $("#searchlname").val();
        var fname = $("#searchfname").val();

        // Add both to the dataString (and URI encode the strings)
        var dataString = {lname: lname, fname: fname}
        // Check that at least one has any content
        if(lname != '' || fname != '')

            // Your ajax query
```

In your PHP code, you just add the new parameter into your query:

```
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];

// Now we will build the search string
$search_str = '';
if ($lname) {
    $search_str = "WHERE lname LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($lname) . "%'";
}

if ($fname) {
    // Check if we have something in the search string, 
    // if we do, add an AND to the statement.
    // If we don't have one, we'll add the WHERE instead.
    $search_str .= $search_str ? ' AND ' : 'WHERE ';
    $search_str .= "fname LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($fname) . "%'";
}

// If neither $lname or $fname contains any data, the query will return all patiens
$sql_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tblpatients` {$search_str} order by `patient_id` LIMIT 15");

// ... the rest of your code.
```

Comment: it's not fetching the data

Comment: i got an `Notice: Undefined index: fname in D:\Program Files\Xammp\htdocs\_system-parts\my_search\search.php on line 12` which is the `$fname = $_POST['fname']; ` and also at  `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\Program Files\Xammp\htdocs\_system-parts\my_search\search.php on line 31`
`

Comment: Then you're not sending the dataString correctly. The other error is because the query fails.

Comment: `var lname = $("#searchlname").val();
 var fname = $("#searchfname").val();

 var dataString = 'lname=' + encodeURIComponent(lname) + 'fname=' + encodeURIComponent(fname);` and #searchlname and #searchfname are the id of my inputs.

Comment: ive tried putting `echo $lname;` and both the inputs of lname and fname displayed but when i tried `echo $fname` doesnt display a thing

Comment: i see the problem of query failure, it's at this line `$search_str = "WHERE lname LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($lname) . "%";` and this `$search_str .= "fname LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($fname) . "%";` its missing `'`

Comment: i fix it i change `var dataString = 'lname=' + encodeURIComponent(lname) + '&fname=' + encodeURIComponent(fname);` to `var dataString = {lname: lname, fname: fname}` the first lname is the POST name and 2nd is the value same goes to the fname

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this perhaps where you build the query based upon the existence of first/lastnames - not tested but might give an idea

```
$search_name = !empty( $_POST['lname'] ) ? $_POST['lname'] : false;
$firstname = !empty( $_POST['fname'] ) ? $_POST['fname'] : false;

if( $search_name ){

    $clauses=array();

    $clauses[]="`lname` like '%$search_name%'";

    if( $firstname ) $clauses[]="`fname` like '%$firstname%'";

    $search = implode( ' AND ', $clauses );

    $sql_res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tblpatients` WHERE {$search} order by `patient_id` LIMIT 15");


    /* rest of the commands...*/

}
```

Comment: Should i add something in the in the JAVASCRIPT?. like something in the datastrings?